# Objective-C: How to pass a tree of objects to a remote distributed object?

Tags: objective-c, exception, deep-copy, distributed-objects

I have a class called Node which contains a set of parameters and an NSMutableArray called subNodes. One process creates one Node object as a root of the tree and uses the subNodes arrays to create a large tree of Nodes. This entire tree should be passed to another process, so I set up an NSConnection:

```
Node *tree;
// ...create Node-Tree...
NSConnection *otherProcess = [NSConnection connectionWithRegisteredName:@"MyApp"
                                           host:nil];
MyObj *remoteObj = (MyObj*) [[otherProcess rootProxy] retain];
[remoteObj setNodeTree:tree];
```

The communication itself works, the remote method 'setNodeTree', which expects the root-Node will be called. However, the transfer of the tree doesn't work. I had to implement a copyWithZone method for the Node class:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
  Node *nodeCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];

  [nodeCopy setSize:[self size]];
  [nodeCopy setSubnodes:[[self subnodes] copyWithZone:zone]];

  return nodeCopy;
}
```

But the client terminates with the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: '[NOTE: this exception originated in the server.]
Cannot create BOOL from object <Node: 0x10018f640> of class NSDistantObject'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
  0  CoreFoundation   0x00007fff81f687b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
  1  libobjc.A.dylib  0x00007fff823a80f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
  2  Foundation       0x00007fff8831e0c3 -[NSConnection sendInvocation:internal:] + 4304
  3  CoreFoundation   0x00007fff81f3a98c ___forwarding___ + 860
  4  CoreFoundation   0x00007fff81f36a68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
  5  MyProgram        0x00000001000015d5 main + 260
  6  MyProgram        0x0000000100000fa8 start + 52
  7  ???              0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Any ideas what went wrong here? Apparently a BOOL variable is expected somewhere, but the Node doesn't contain any and there is no method used which expects or returns a BOOL.

Comment: If your `subnodes` property is either `retain` or `copy`, you are leaking an instance in `[nodeCopy setSubnodes:[[self subnodes] copyWithZone:zone]];`.  I've gotten all kinds of weird errors from improperly implemented `copyWithZone:` implementations.

Comment: Ooops, thanks for the hint. That was a leftover from trying to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives are possible:

- serialization and deserialization of whole tree,
- shared memory between processes.

For performance and code readability, my preference goes to shared memory. A reference start is [shmget(2) manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man2/shmget.2.html).

Comment: I have tried serializing and passing the entire tree, but the Exception remains the same. Shared memory is a problem because I don't always know in advance how large the tree will become.